# Don't want SplitView Controller as rootViewController

Tags: ios, ipad

Apple documentation says that any application using a split view controller should make it as a root view controller. But i am struck at a state where, my login screen should redirect me to a split view controller. Is there a way to achieve this?

I am Using storyboards and new to programming. Kindly help.

Comment: Have you considered presenting the login screen modally over the split view?

Comment: that's a quite common issue. changing the `rootViewController` of your applicaion's main `UIWindow` will do the trick.

Comment: @prasaadem what do you think about my suggestion?

Comment: @Wain I tried to present it modally but the program crashes that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quite common way to solve this issue to change the `rootViewController` of your applications main `UIWindow` (which again is a *property* of your `AppDelegate`) after a successful login.

So, the *initial view controller* of your app needs to be your `LoginViewController` that handles the login. After a successful login, you can do something like this:

```
- (void)switchToMainInterface
{
    // Change the root view controller of the application window to the main storyboard
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    UISplitViewController *mainSplitViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainSplitViewController"];

    UIWindow *mainApplicationWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    mainApplicationWindow.rootViewController = mainSplitViewController;
}
```

Note that this code is just dummy code to make my suggestion a bit more tangible, it makes the following assumptions:

- you have a *Storyboard* called `Main` in your application bundle
- within this `Main` *Storyboard* you have a `UISplitViewController` with the *Storyboard ID* `MainSplitViewController` so that you can instantiate it programmatically
- you need to `import AppDelegate.h` to get access to the root `UIWindow`

Answer (score 0):

Link your `LoginViewController` to a `UIViewcontroller`. In this controller drag an `UIContainerView`, and embed your `UISplitViewController` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom segue class and implemented the following code. I am not sure what it does to my application. It seems a bit high level code to me as I am an amature but it works fine. Hope you find it useful.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

    {

            //Override point for customization after application launch.
        //    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        //    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
        //    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

            return YES;

    }
```

Commented the above code, I believe this is to pause UISplitViewController from loading into UIWindow.

And my custom segue --> segue.m is as follows..

```
#import "Seague.h"
```

@implementation Seague

```
-(void)perform
{

        UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
        UIViewController *destinationViewController = (UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController;

        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)destinationViewController;
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
        splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

        UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
        window.rootViewController = destinationViewController;
        window.rootViewController = sourceViewController;

        [UIView transitionWithView:sourceViewController.view.window duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{
            window.rootViewController = destinationViewController;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
    }
```

@end

This segue is triggered when my login button is pressed and the login details are valid.
My rootViewController is the viewController that has my login button and not UISplitViewController.

Reference: This is not a code I wrote. Found it somewhere on web after searching for 2 days. Will update the source link for reference soon.

Thankyou all for your responses :)